# React app refuses to import from package that was installed from filesystem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, monorepo

I am trying to build a monorepo with a separate `shared` package (written in typescript) and `client` package (initially generated using `create-react-app --template typescript`)

In `shared` I define types and data will be shared between server and client. I imported the shared package into client using `npm i ../shared` which creates the following entry in `package.json`: `"shared": "file:../shared"`. In `node_modules` I have a corresponding symlink to the actual package code

[image]

In `shared` i followed one tutorial and added the followind entries to `package.json`:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
},
"files": [
    "dist/**/*"
],
```

Now the problem: in `client` typescript is able to perfectly infer all types and I can import types defined in `shared`. However, when it comes to actual data, webpack throws an error on build

[image]

The actual compiled module looks rather cryptic:

```
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(m, k);
    if (!desc || ("get" in desc ? !m.__esModule : desc.writable || desc.configurable)) {
      desc = { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } };
    }
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, desc);
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __exportStar = (this && this.__exportStar) || function(m, exports) {
    for (var p in m) if (p !== "default" && !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(exports, p)) __createBinding(exports, m, p);
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__exportStar(require("./enums"), exports);
__exportStar(require("./interfaces"), exports);
```

How do I set up it to at least compile? Please feel free to point out if I am doing something fundamentally wrong, in the end I just want to share some typescript code between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Turns out I just had to change `type` in `package.json` in `shared` from `module` to `commonjs`. Because while typescript was compiling to some sort of `commonjs` modules, `shared` declared it was using es modules and webpack naturally didn't find `export` declarations.